# ImageView with Non-Transparent Background Image

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I know similar questions asked a lot of times but this one is different. I've got a background image and I am supposed to use this for ImageViews. Picture is not rectangular and not transparent, you can view it from [here](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2j1qx5t&s=8#.VfjLCxGqpBc) or see below [image: s]

This is what I've tried:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="#999999"
          android:padding="10dp"
          android:gravity="center">

    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="170dp">

        <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_background"/>

        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/random_pic"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and result looks like this:

[image]

When I remove the ImageView result is this:

[image]

As you can see, ImageView doesn't have the same shape as background. I've tried several different methods as well, like

- putting background directly to the ImageView, or
- changing the View to ImageView and use the rounded image as background, or source image of it

they had no effect. I've also tried to change the order, I've put the View after the ImageView, but then since the rounded background is not transparent, I couldn't see the ImageView, all I saw was the white background image.

It is not possible to achieve without changing the rounded_background.png file itself, right? Cause I know that if the background was transparent it would've worked.

Thanks

**EDIT:** There is no way to achieve this without changing the image. If one wants to learn the only way to achieve that, he/she should see the accepted answer.

Comment: I am not getting you. if image will remove then what should done? Background will remove or Background become transparent?
If you need both at same time then use Relative layout and add Background image in this layout  and set image view inside this Relative layout.

Comment: I want to change the shape of ImageView. You see the white background right? I want my ImageView in that shape. Using RelativeLayout as you said didn't work, it is the same as above.

Comment: ohk you mean your image upper side have curve like in your background image have . right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your problem solution.

1. make your background image transparent like this.
   [image]
2. set your main image as FrameLayout background image.
3. and this background is ImageView background image.

   ```
   <FrameLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="170dp"
       android:background="@drawable/randominage">

       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="@drawable/rounded_background"
           android:scaleType="fitXY" />
   </FrameLayout>
   ```

Comment: Thanks for this, and sorry if I couldn't make it clear. I already know that this way it is possible, but this requires to change the current background image. I am searching for a way to do this without changing the background image.

Comment: Since there is no way to achieve this without changing the image itself, I am going to accept your answer